# Organizing Calculation Code in Laravel: Models or Controllers?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

First to get this our of the way I'm a Front-end guy and for fun I'm trying to learn more backend stuff with Laravel 4. However I've gotten my self lost and looking for some guidance to get me going in the right direction.

I'm working on build a simple app with sports stats(soccer). I've created a test database with one table that has some very basic info that is all integers other then the name of the team. In the future I would like to move the teams to a different table and set up some relationships but one step at a time here.

So what I would like to do is take the data to some simple calculations then output that to a restful controller. So things like:

wins + loses + draws = games played

(wins * 3) + (draws) = points

**My first question is:** how do I set up the code so that it will loop through all of the rows in the table and return the calculation for each row? **Secondly:** is it better to do this in the model or in the controller?

Answer (score 3):

**In answer to your first question:**

After you have the "games played" data in one of your database tables, you could start out by getting the "games played" data in one of your controller files (perhaps a controller named "Games_Controller",) like this:

```
public function get_games_list()
{
    $this->layout->nest(
        'content',
        'games.games_list',
        array('games' => Game::getGames())
    );
}
```

But before this will work, we need to add something to your model file (perhaps a model named "Game",) like this:

```
public static function getGames()
{
    return Game::order_by('id')->get();
}
```

From there, you could use the data returned from `getGames()` in a view (perhaps a view named "games_list.blade.php",) like this:

```
<?php foreach ($games as $game) : ?>
<?php echo $game->id ?>">
<?php echo $game->result ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

*(Where `result` could be the "win/loss" data from your database table.)*

---

**In answer to your second question:**

It's not a bad idea to move calculation-type code into your model.  But do keep in mind that there [arguments related to](http://joncairns.com/2013/04/fat-model-skinny-controller-is-a-load-of-rubbish/) the "fat model, skinny controller" idea, as well.

---

For more information, you may want to take a look at this [Laravel Blog Tutorial](http://codehappy.daylerees.com/the-blog-tutorial) as a reference for further work with Laravel!

Comment: the fat model/skinny controller view is a little dated now, to be sure. That's why you now have the DCI pattern for models - everything is still in the model, but you only pull in methods and properties that you need at run-time. Good answer, btw.

Comment: So would the result in the controller be a function that generates the result in the modal? I confusion lays with how I loop through 10 or more rows of data or is this done automatically for all the rows in the database?

Comment: @user2356346 So, (in the example above,) the `getGames()` function in the model will gather the "games" (win/loss) data from your database table.  The controller calls this `getGames()` function and sends the list/array of "games" data to your view.  Finally, in the view, you are looping through the "games" data by using the `foreach ($games as $game)` line.  Does that clear up any confusion for you? :)